# glGetProgramIv() doesn't change the pointer sent to it

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have this function:

```
void GetAllUniforms(unsigned int prog) {
  int total = -1;
  glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &total);
  printf("total & prog: %d %d\n", total, prog);
  for(int i=0; i<total; ++i)  {
    int name_len=-1, num=-1;
    GLenum type = GL_ZERO;
    char name[100];
    glGetActiveUniform(prog, i, sizeof(name)-1,
        &name_len, &num, &type, name);
    name[name_len] = 0;
    unsigned int location = glGetUniformLocation(prog, name);
    printf("Name: %s/Number: %d/Location: %d\n", name, num, location);
  }
}
```

It's purpose is simple, get all uniforms and print them, 
however, let's say I ran this function, right?
It would give me:

```
Running newpmo/build/out
total & prog: -1 1
```

It's clear, there are no active uniforms in my glsl shaders, which is ridiculous cause I have a WorldMatrix multiplying a Position Vector to get Gl_Position, and upon further debugging I found that if I set total to another number, let's say 5, I get this:

```
Running newpmo/build/out
total & prog: 5 1
Name: /Number: -1/Location: -1
Name: /Number: -1/Location: -1
Name: /Number: -1/Location: -1
Name: /Number: -1/Location: -1
Name: /Number: -1/Location: -1
```

This is pretty odd, cause it shows that glGetProgramiv is not actually affecting total in any way, even though I sent it my address and the program is compiled and linked properly!

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_LINK_STATUS` returns whether the program has been successfully linked or not. So even if that line had worked correctly, the result is *not* a value you should be looping over. Given what you're trying to do, the value you want to query is `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS`.

However, on to your principle problem. You are getting some kind of OpenGL error from this (BTW: always check for OpenGL errors). I know that because the only reason that function would not set the variable is if it errors out. So [go fetch the error](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Testing_for_errors).

Since it's not an obvious error (like passing the wrong enum or something), what's probably happening is not something that's visible from here. That is, you're not passing a valid program to this function. You could be passing a shader object instead of a program object, or you could be passing a value you didn't get from `glCreateProgram`.

Comment: My bad fot Gl_Link_Status, I put that there to try debugging but I ended up leaving it, it does.the same for glactiveuniiforms...